# Asp:ImageButton not firing onCommand event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am facing a problem with an asp:ImageButton that doens't fire the onCommand event while im doing debug...
Im doing this on a .ascx file i dunno if it has something to do with it or not.

My html:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDel" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/delete_grey.png" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>' OnCommand="btnDel_Command"/>
```

My code behind :

```
Protected Sub btnDel_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
        Dim sFileID As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()

        DeleteMessageFile(sFileID)
    End Sub
```

Comment: How and where are you adding the `UserControl`? If it is dynamic and you are not rebinding it after PostBack, then the command will not fire.

Comment: I dunno what you are talking about sorry, but this is all i can say.
I have a master page, then i have a aspx page that is binded to that master page...
The aspx page calls the ascx which there is the imagebutton.

The method btnDel_Command is in the code behind of the ascx page

Comment: Try OnClick event not OnCommand.

Comment: @MaCron But that way i don't get the CommentArgument, and i need to get that id from there...

Comment: Yes you can get the command argument. Its part of the control.  You need to use OnClick because OnCommand doesn't exist for an Image Button.